# When Sha256 and md5 are added together

Tags: hash, asp-classic

When Sha256 and md5 are added together include in page

```
   <!--#include file="hash/sha256.asp"-->
   <!---#include file="hash/md5.asp"--->
```

gives this error

```
Microsoft VBScript derleme hatasý hata '800a0411'

Ad yeniden tanýmlandý

/3wPay/include/hash/md5.asp, satır 3

Private Const BITS_TO_A_BYTE = 8
--------------^
```

but it works alone when md5 or sha256 is included.
How can I run both together

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what that error says, but I'm assuming that BITS_TO_A_BYTE is already defined. I would clean up both of those files and created a 3rd file with all of your constants, and remove the constants from both of those files.

When you create your 3rd file, only define each constant once.

Then include it whenever you use either md5.asp or sha256.asp

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, looks like you have 2 constants with the same name. A more efficient and compact alternative in my opinion would be to use the `System.Security.Cryptography.X` object, which supports MD5, SHA1, SHA256, SHA384 and SHA512.

The example code below also allows you to encode as Hex or Base64:

```vb
<%

    Function Hash(ByVal Input, Alg, Encoding)

        Dim hAlg, hEnc

        Set hAlg = CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography." & Get_Hash_Obj(Alg))
        Set hEnc = CreateObject("System.Text.UTF8Encoding")

            Hash = BinaryEncode(hAlg.ComputeHash_2(hEnc.GetBytes_4(Input)),Encoding)

        Set hEnc = Nothing
        Set hAlg = Nothing

    End Function

    Function Get_Hash_Obj(Alg)

        ' Get the cryptography class name for the specified hashing algorithm,
        ' return the class name for SHA1 if not found

        Select Case uCase(Alg)

            Case "MD5"
                Get_Hash_Obj = "MD5CryptoServiceProvider"
            Case "SHA1"
                Get_Hash_Obj = "SHA1CryptoServiceProvider"
            Case "SHA256"
                Get_Hash_Obj = "SHA256Managed"
            Case "SHA384"
                Get_Hash_Obj = "SHA384Managed"
            Case "SHA512"
                Get_Hash_Obj = "SHA512Managed"
            Case Else
                Get_Hash_Obj = "SHA1CryptoServiceProvider"

        End Select

    End Function

    Function BinaryEncode(Binary, Encoding)

        Dim Enc

        Encoding = lCase(Encoding)

        Set Enc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DomDocument").CreateElement("encode")
        
            If Encoding = "base64" OR Encoding = "b64" Then
                
                ' base64 string
                
                Enc.DataType = "bin.base64"
                Enc.NodeTypedValue = Binary
                BinaryEncode = Enc.Text 
            
            Else
            
                ' Hexadecimal string
                
                Enc.DataType = "bin.hex"
                Enc.NodeTypedValue = Binary
                BinaryEncode = Enc.Text 
            
            End If
        
        Set Enc = Nothing
            
    End Function

%>
```

Example:

```vb
Response.Write Hash("Hello World","SHA256","Hex")
Response.Write Hash("Hello World","SHA256","Base64") ' Or B64
```

Output:

```
a591a6d40bf420404a011733cfb7b190d62c65bf0bcda32b57b277d9ad9f146e
pZGm1Av0IEBKARczz7exkNYsZb8LzaMrV7J32a2fFG4=
```